# rails dot notation no longer works for accessing hash values gives NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.3

I'm using `rails 5` with `ruby 2.3.3` . Today I added a gem, there was a version conflict so I took the gem out. Since then dot notation such as `hash.test` no longer works. It gives `NoMethodError: private method test called for {:test=>"value"}:Hash`

How can I access hashes with dot notation again?

Comment: What is the gem you removed?

Comment: https://github.com/svenfuchs/hashr

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you're using to use dot-notation to access a hash is probably using [`method_missing`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) to trap your dot-notation method calls. But everything has a `test` method because [`Kernel#test`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-test) exists and everything includes `Kernel`; also, pretty much everything in `Kernel` is private because `Kernel` is where methods go that we want to pretend are functions. For example:

```
> 'pancakes'.test
NoMethodError: private method `test' called for "pancakes":String
```

I suspect that you problem is your choice of `:test` as hash key.